# Minimize factories in test?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.4

Currently I am using many factories `factory()` in Test class, is there a way to reduce to 1 so I can only use `factory(Something::class)` in a test method?

Reason I used many because I have to pass some foreign keys.

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create();

$token = factory(Token::class)->create([
    'user_id' => $user->id,
]);

$provider = factory(Provider::class)->create([
    'user_id'       => $user->id,
    'token_id'      => $token->id,
]);

$something = factory(Something::class)->create([
    'provider_id' => $provider->id,
]);

   // Now test with $something
```

Comment: Do you need to know `$user` or any of the foreign keys? Or just do something with `$something`?

Comment: I don't care which `$user` it is. All the factory use faker,

Comment: I just need to use  `factory(Something::class)` with $something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such syntax:

```
$factory->define(Something::class, function ($faker) {
    return [
        'title' => $faker->title,
        'content' => $faker->paragraph,
        'provider_id' => function () {
            return factory(Provider::class)->create()->id;
        }
    ];
});

$factory->define(Provider::class, function ($faker) {
    $user = factory(User:class)->create();
    return [
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'token_id' => function () {
            return factory(Token::class)->create(['user_id' => $user->id])->id;
        }
    ];
});
```

and then in your tests you can only use:

```
$something = factory(Something::class)->create();
```

Be aware depending on your needs it can cause some side effects - for example when using Provider factory, user will be always created what might be fine or not depending on your tests. Of course if needed you can always created helper method that will wrap all those methods you showed and return only something and then in your test you can only use:

```
$something = $this->createSomething();
```